# Modifying Bug report message generated by MadExcept

Tags: delphi, exception, madexcept

The bug report generated by MadExcept shows computer name and other such details which is a security concern. 
How can I modify the message and remove such values from it.

Answer (score 4):

In your madExcept exception handler, you have access to the bug report header fields. A madExcept exception handler looks like this:

```
procedure ExceptionHandler(const exceptIntf: IMEException; var handled: boolean);
```

You can remove fields from the bug report header by operating on the supplied `exceptIntf` interface.

For instance define this helper function:

```
procedure RemoveField(const Fields: IMEFields; const FieldName: UnicodeString);
var 
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Index := exc.BugReportHeader.FindItem('computer name');
  if Index<>-1 then 
    Fields.Delete(Index);
end;
```

Then call it from inside your exception handler like this:

```
RemoveField(exceptIntf.BugReportHeader, 'computer name');
```

Comment: Hello David, thanx for the answer. I am using CreateBugReport method to generate the bug report. How can I do with this?

Comment: There are really many ways to do this. Remember that I don't have any knowledge of how you use ME. You could use `RegisterExceptionHandler` for instance. Or perhaps `RegisterBugReportCallback`. You have found the documentation?